# how to create contents in an activity dynamically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an android application, in which user can take a test and get his score.
So, I have created a database with 50 questions and I want to choose a question number randomly using Random class and retrieve that question from database and show it in an Activity. And by clicking "Next question" button in the activity, I want the same activity to be loaded with different question. How can I write the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to load the same Activity *again*?

I'd create an activity (fragment), with the main design, and a function (call it `reDisplay()`), which displays the question, the answers, etc. In the `onCreate()`, I'd call this function, and every time, the user clicked on the "Next question" text, I'd save them answers, and call the `reDisplay()` function, to show an other questin.

Comment: I have created an Activity and in onCreate() I have inserted into database and called a method which retrieves data from database. In the onClickListener for "next question" button using Intents I have called the same class, so its tuples in the databse are again inserted. How can I solve this, I want the records to be created only once and different questions to be generated by clicking "next button". Please suggest a solution.